# VB.NET - Mouse Coordinates

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, mouse, coordinates

I have a vb.net application, and I want to know how to find the coordinates of the pointer (mouse) when it is clicked on the form. Not much else to say, so I'll leave it like that.. :D

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Very simple code to put the mouse coords in a text box

```
Private Sub Form1_MouseClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles Me.MouseClick
    Dim MPx As Point = MousePosition()
    TextBox1.Text = MPx.ToString

End Sub
```

tried and tested,

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this

```
Private Sub Form1_MouseClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles Me.MouseClick
     TextBox1.Text = e.Location.ToString()
End Sub
```

I would not advise

```
Private Sub Form1_MouseClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles Me.MouseClick
     TextBox1.Text = MousePosition().ToString()
End Sub
```

because it may change after you first click down on the button because you moved your mouse. So its always better if you are doing a calculation to assign the location to a variable or in e.location case it is already a separate variable that doesn't change. This is also why it is a better choice than MousePosition since mouseposition will constantly change while its in this click function rather then e.location will remain the same till it leaves the mouseclick event.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for the `mousedown` event. Mind that, if you are looking for actual screen coordinates, you might have to perform some calculations as well or use Windows API to get the coordinates fast.